# Is writing std::atomic thread safe in the area of read lock

Tags: c++, thread-safety, stdatomic, readwritelock

I've a `std::map<std::string, std::tuple<int, int, std::atomic<int>>> mp`. The map can be read and write parallel so I use a read-write lock to keep it thread safe.

I want to know if I can write `std::get<2>(mp["someKey"])` in the read lock area.

```
void read() {
    // read lock area
    std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> read_lock{mtx};
    // "someKey" exists already
    std::get<2>(mp["someKey"]).store(2);
}
```

I've tried to do some tests, it seems that it works but I don't know if it's incorrect and gives me a coredump someday.

Comment: No, because it modifies the map if the key is missing?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  I'm sure that the key must exist already.

Comment: Then it should be safe, but why not use `.at()` instead if the key must exist? Or `.find()` + `assert`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, note that `mp["someKey"]` modifies the map and is not thread-safe. If no key exists yet, `operator[]` will create a new value-initialized key/value pair.
See also [Why is std::map::operator[] considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8800770/5740428)

Instead, you should use `mp.at("someKey")` or `mp.find("someKey")`:

```cpp
// OK, exception thrown if key doesn't exist yet
std::get<2>(mp.at("someKey")).store(2);

// OK, nothing happens if key doesn't exist yet
if (auto it = mp.find("someKey"); it != mp.end()) {
    std::get<2>(*it).store(2);
}
```

`.store(2);` is thread-safe because writing to a `std::atomic` from multiple threads simultaneously is safe.
The `std::shared_lock` isn't necessary to ensure this. However, the `std::shared_lock` ensures that the surrounding `std::pair` cannot be destroyed by another thread so it must be kept.

#### Note on const-correctness

Const-correctness would have prevented the bug with `mp["someKey"]`. If you only hold a read-lock, it's good practice to work with a `const&` to prevent accidental modifications:

```cpp
std::as_const(mp)["someKey"]); // error

const auto& cmp = mp;
cmp["someKey"]; // error
```

#### Note on `std::tuple`

`std::tuple` outside of variadic templates is always questionable.
It's almost always better to have meaningful names:

```cpp
struct entry {
    int a, b; // obviously, use better names than a, b, c
    std::atomic<int> c;
};

// ...

if (auto it = mp.find("someKey"); it != mp.end()) {
    it->c.store(2);
}
```